# Xcode 14 ios 16 how to login a Drupal site from an iPhone app?

Tags: swift, xcode

What library/tools are available for iPhone developers to:

- login the Drupal site (username password)
- access the page with a loggin status

For example, I'd like to fill a UITableView with data from the Drupal page. Thanks!

I using Xcode 14 swift ios 16

Comment: Use API. [Follow the Drupal instructions](https://www.drupal.org/docs/mobile-drupal-sites/native-mobile-application-development#s-native-mobile-application-capabilities)